# Remove the input string from the original myString

Tags: java, string, indexing, substring

I am trying to remove the input string from the public string myString

myString = "Hello"

removeS("el") will return "Hlo"

Heres my code below and the problem in it is incompatible types: java.lang.String cannot be converted to int in my String result. I would like it if you used substring() and indexOf() to solve my issue and not use any other power tools than those. How would I go about fixing this.

```
public class StringI
{
    public String myString;

public String removeS(String s){

    myString = "Hello";
    
    
    String result = s.substring(myString);

    return result;
    }

public static void main(String args[]){

StringI n = new StringI();

n.removeS("el");


}




}
```

Comment: `s.substring(int)` accepts an integer, not a String. I have no idea what you want.

Comment: if i did s.indexOf() would that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to get the first half and the last half, then piece them together like so:

```
String result = myString.substring(0, myString.indexOf(s))+myString.substring(myString.indexOf(s)+s.length());
```

Since **.indexOf()** returns the position of `s`, we can use substring to start from the start of the String to that position, then use another substring to get the final part.

The following program:

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
 
 public class Main {
     public static String removeS(String s){
         String myString = "Hello";
         String result = myString.substring(0, myString.indexOf(s))+myString.substring(myString.indexOf(s)+s.length(), myString.length());
         return result;
     }
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(removeS("el"));
 }
}
```

Produces:

```
Hlo
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Substring: You can make this into two part:

```java
public class StringI
{
    public String myString;

    public String removeS(String s){
        myString = "Hello";
        
        // Before the `s`
        String part1 = myString.substring(0, myString.indexOf(s));
        // After the `s`
        String part2 = myString.substring(myString.indexOf(s) + s.length());

        return part1 + part2;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        StringI n = new StringI();
        String result = n.removeS("el");
        
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to do is-

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String myString = "Hello";
    String removeString="el";
    System.out.println(myString.replace(removeString,""));
}
```

Comment: This removes all of them, rather than the first occurence.

Comment: You can use replaceFirst to replace only firsy occurence.